# SQL Server - Generate date field data in where clause

Tags: sql-server

My query is

```
Select * from Orders 
where ordersdate Between '2013-10-10 00:00:00.00' and '2013-10-10 23:59:59.997'
```

I need to run this query on daily basis and it should be previous day dates. so how to generate dates in above format is what im struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME

/* set the end date to midnight of the previous day */
SET @EndDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 121), 121) 
/* set the start date to 1 day previously (thereby getting midnight to midnight) */
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, -1, @EndDate)

/* you could use between, but orders placed at midnight might be counted twice (on subsequent day reports) */
Select * from Orders where ordersdate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate

/* or you could use >= and < to guarantee that a order placed at midnight will only be counted once */
Select * from Orders where ordersdate >= @StartDate AND ordersdate < @EndDate
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * 
from Orders
where ordersdate >= cast(dateadd(d, -1, getdate()) as date)
and ordersdate < cast(getdate() as date)
```

Instead of the additonal `time` you can use `>=` yesterday's date and `<` today.

Comment: Note: this will only work if the column "orders" is the order date of the order. @Conrad Jagger you need to make sure the column you're comparing to the date is the order date of the order which will probably be called something like orderDate or order_date

Comment: The date datatype was introduced in SQL Server 2008 and isn't available on SQL Server SQL Server 2005 and earlier. To extract the date from a datetime on these systems, I use:  `cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime)`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from orders 
where datediff(d, ordersdate, getdate()) = 1
```

/edit/
As per Jason Musgrove comment - such query is easy to write and understand, but depend on rows count may become quite inefficent.

Comment: I believe that it is inefficient to use functions on columns when an alternative is available - it may prevent any optimisations (indexes, statistics, etc) from being used, and requires extra CPU activity per row.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that SQL could optimize such kind of functions usage - but I just tried on some tables (where datetime field is indexed) and seems you are correct.

Answer (score -1):

taking a slightly different approach (but probably not as good as Arvo's Answer) and there are quicker ways to perform the cast

```
select * 
from orders 
where cast(ordersdate as varchar(11))  = cast( dateadd(dd,-1,getdate()) as varchar(11) )
```

Comment: I highly doubt that casting to a string, and then performing a string comparison is "quicker". Its my belief that those operations incur a significant computational overhead.

Comment: i didn't suggest it was quicker, just that it was a different approach